# How to take input from user and change directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How do I take input from a user and then i.e. change a directory based upon that input.

Example, lets say I ask, please type in directory of A
when pressing enter, the directory should change to it and echo out the working directory to the user.

```
@ECHO OFF 
:: This batch file takes input from the user, delete, copy and install 
new files. 
ECHO Please enter the location of your Zibo folder:
set mydir=%CD%
PAUSE
ECHO your working directory is:
ECHO %mydir%
PAUSE
```

Comment: Take a look at [`set /P`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Set /P` to request user input. To find out how, enter `set /?` at the Command Prompt, and read the output. To change directory, you'd use `CD|ChDir`, its usage information is also available at the Command Prompt when entering `cd /?`.

Here's an example:

```bat
@Echo Off 
:GetInput
Set "ZiboDir="
Rem Request input from the user. 
Set /P "ZiboDir=Please enter the location of your Zibo directory: "
Rem If input is not a directory ask again
For %%G In ("%ZiboDir%") Do If "%%~aG" Lss "d" If "%%~aG" GEq "-" (
    GoTo GetInput) Else GoTo GetInput
Rem Valid directory detected so continuing
Echo Your Zibo directory is %ZiboDir%
Pause
Rem Make the Zibo directory the current directory
CD /D "%ZiboDir%"
Echo Your current directory is %CD%
Pause
```

Comment: Thank you, excellent will try that. So if you then want to do normal file commands like mkdir, rd, cp  you just use those commands like you would normally with no special characters?

Comment: @TomKnudsen, your `MD|MkDir`, `RD|RmDir` and `Copy` commands can still be run in the same manner as those are internal commands. Any executables, located in `%PATH%` will still run the same. The only difference is that anything which was in your current directory previous to changing directory, would now need to use a full or relative path. Conversely, any files used by that process, would be path free!

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old thread I thought I would comment as I myself needed the same thing a while back and found users were entering the wrong location and so decided it would be a better idea to allow the user to select the directory using the Windows GUI in an effort to prevent user error.

Hope you/someone else find(s) this useful:

```
@echo off &cls
mode con: cols=60 lines=5 & color f0
setlocal

echo. Please select the location of your Zibo folder. &>nul timeout /t 3

set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please select the location of your Zibo folder.',0,0).self.path""

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "Zibofolder=%%I"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo. You selected: "%Zibofolder%"

echo. &echo. Press any key to exit. &>nul timeout /t -1 &exit /B
```